# «Что», тире и запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Розенталь говорит, что мы можем заменять конструкцию «, что» на длинное тире. Так-то оно так, но иногда в некоторых конструкциях я опасаюсь следовать данному принципу. Приведу смущающие примеры:

«Я думаю — так делать не надо».
«Розенталь говорит — мы можем заменять конструкцию».

Я часто встречаю в книгах, что в таких случаях используют и запятую, и двоеточие (без пунктуации прямой речи). Но можно ли так? Придерживаться ли правила Розенталя, либо тут как хочешь, так и пишешь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дословное высказывание можно оформить различными способами: прямая речь, бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП), сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП), вводное предложение.

Я думаю, что надо быть благодарной тому случаю, той роли (СПП, косвенная речь).

Думаю: надо ползти ближе к воде. Я теперь думаю: надо просить его, чтобы он меня немедленно направил в какой-либо город. (БСП, двоеточие).

Я думаю ― надо профессора про нее спросить (БСП, тире).

Но, думаю, надо выжить.Я думаю, надо написать что-то попроще, подешевле (вводное предложение).

Выбор зависит от распространенности предложения, от желания автора **выделить** прямое высказывание. У прямой речи наибольшая выделительная способность, дальше - двоеточие и тире в БСП, запятая при обособлении вводного предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Перефразируйте близко к тексту и увидите явственно: "по-моему, так делать не надо."

Comment: Придерживаться ли правила Розенталя, либо тут как хочешь, так и пишешь? Так стоит вопрос.